# If you are a dog and your owner suggests that you wear a sweater suggest that he wear a tail. (Author Fran Lebowitz)

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

> If you are a dog and your owner suggests that you wear a sweater suggest that he wear a tail. (Author Fran Lebowitz)

How a person could wear a tail?

Comment: Come on, kids wear costumes with tails. So why not adults? You can sew a tail onto your pants.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about the English language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can't.  That's the point: it's absurd for a human to wear a tail, and equally absurd for a dog to wear a sweater.

The logic is weak since dogs can wear sweaters, but, such as it is, that's it.

Comment: A human could attach an artificial tail to their lower back, using some form of adhesive. That would be inconvenient and annoying for them, just as an artificial 'coat' (a sweater) would be for a dog.